# mysql group_concat in joins

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT web_order_item.od_pcode) AS items, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT woi_id) AS woi_ids 
    FROM web_order 
JOIN web_order_item USING(od_id) 
JOIN customer_master ON customer_master.VC_CUSTOMER_CODE = web_order.p_vendor 
LEFT JOIN production_item ON production_item.ItemID IN (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT woi_id)) AND QCStatus <> 'received' 
WHERE
   web_order.od_date >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1357257600) 
   AND web_order.od_date <= FROM_UNIXTIME(1359936000) 
   AND web_order.od_id > 0 
   AND 1 
GROUP BY web_order.od_id 
ORDER BY web_order.od_id DESC
```

This query throws an error

> General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function

What am I missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting the original record in it's entirety, and then you are doing a group concat on the web_order_item, this will produce a single row because of the DISTINCT property, if there is more than one record, you are grouping there, and then trying to group again...what are you group by'ing for at the end anyway? there's no aggregation, an order by will suffice. take out the group by...or change the group by to include all relevant items before the group concat...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT web_order_item.od_pcode) AS items, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT woi_id) AS woi_ids 
FROM web_order 
JOIN web_order_item USING(od_id) 
JOIN customer_master ON customer_master.VC_CUSTOMER_CODE = web_order.p_vendor 
LEFT JOIN production_item ON production_item.ItemID IN (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT woi_id))     AND QCStatus <> 'received' 
WHERE
web_order.od_date >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1357257600) 
AND web_order.od_date <= FROM_UNIXTIME(1359936000) 
AND web_order.od_id > 0 
AND 1 
GROUP BY items, woi_ids 
ORDER BY web_order.od_id DESC
```

Hop this helps

Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html